The three trees in Mistral's "Tres árboles"
In Gabriela Mistral's poem "Tres árboles", the speaker says he or she came across three fallen trees that have been left behind by the woodcutter. The third stanza describes how one of these trees stretches out its "huge arm with trembling leaves" (Ursula K. Le Guin's translation) towards one of the other trees. The other trees are not described at all.
Here are my questions, which I think are interconnected:

Are these three trees symbols for something else or is the poem mainly an expression of the speaker's sorrow or mourning (duelo, the poem's last word)?
Is there any significance to the number of trees? Since Gabriela Mistral was a very religious poet, one unavoidably thinks of the Trinity, but it's hard to see how that can be relevant to the poem.


"Tres árboles" ("Three trees") is a poem from Mistral's first volume of poetry Desolación published in 1922. As the OP relates, the speaker comes across three trees that have been felled and left behind by the woodcutters. The third verse reads:

Uno torcido, tiende
su brazo inmenso y de follaje trémulo
hacia el otro, y sus heridas
como dos ojos son, llenos de ruego.

which I would translate as:

One, twisted, reaches
its huge arm with trembling leaves
toward another, its wounds
like two eyes full of prayer.

This could simply be the poet passing by a scene of wanton waste, where trees have been felled and abandoned for no purpose. Mistral was a strong nature-lover, and such an image would naturally be painful to her. However, the image of the tree bleeding ("sangre viva en los hendidos leños”) and bearing open wounds in its side ("su costado abierto”) strongly invokes an image of the crucifixion. Indeed, the Chilean author Eduardo Barrios noted in El primer libro de Gabriela Mistral that in Desolación "underneath the poetry, there are always Christian entrails" ("bajo la maravilla poética, siempre la víscera cristiana").
The fallen tree can thus be seen as representing the Christ on the Cross, with the two other trees standing for the other two crucifixions, the two thieves who were crucified by his side on Golgotha. This is also the conclusion reached by Patricia Vargas Sandoval  in her work Sentimientos religiosos en Desolación ("Religious sentiments in Desolación), who wrote "The tree is used as a simple metonymy of the Cross".
